# Deploy Exploded File in WebLogic

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, war

I have to deploy an exploded war file in my local WebLogic Server access by Administration Console.

1. First I am given a war file.
2. Then I extracted it because I have to replace its web.xml
3. From that I have to deploy it to the weblogic.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to go with this:

1. deploy as a WAR package (assuming your WAR is mywar.war)

   - extract only the web.xml via `jar xvf mywar.war WEB-INF/web.xml`
   - modify the web.xml
   - add back the web.xml via `jar uvf mywar.war WEB-INF/web.xml`
   - you can try to extract again and see that the new change has taken effect
2. Deploy as an exploded WAR (ie, as normal OS folder).

   - make sure the folder name is the same as the original WAR name. ie, the folder name should be `mywar.war`.
   - Put all the exploded contents into that folder. The `WEB-INF` is directly under the folder.

Now you can deploy them normally using the `Deployment` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Open console. Go to Deployments -> press Install -> find to path to extracted war files, you should see (open directory) label -> press Next - Next - Finish. You are done, it is deployed.